# Is it possible for a Spring Batch to start a Container with an external app?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, spring-batch, testcontainers

Let's say we have a REST app with its REST end-points that we can wrap in a Docker container.

Let's say our Spring batch's `Item Processor` likes to use the above app to get business logic information about a record it is handling.

We like this REST app to be used solely by the `Spring Batch` process and we don't like the Batch process to communicate with the Production REST app, but to have some kind of it own instance of the REST app.

We also like that this app instance will be created automatically when the Spring Batch process starts, so no extra human intervention or configuration is needed.

Is it possible that the Spring batch will use run and use the REST service as a Docker container (maybe as [testconainer](https://www.testcontainers.org/) or maybe [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?) so it can use it "internally" in some way?

Is this a reasonable architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to:

- create a custom docker network and attach both your Spring Batch app container and REST app container to it. These two containers will only be visible in that network.
- attach your Spring Batch app container to the REST API container so that the item processor can see the REST API endpoint and make calls

You can find the official tutorial about how to create custom docker networks [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks).

Hope this helps.